# jQuery highlightTextarea picking partial matches instead of full match

Tags: jquery, textarea

I use [jQuery highlighttextarea](https://github.com/garysieling/jquery-highlighttextarea) using jquery-2.1.1.min.js to highlight words.

On click of a button, I call a function to highlight specific text

```
$("#btn_me").on("click", function(){
  var words_array = ["His"];
  $('#textarea_me').highlightTextarea({
    words: [{color: "grey",  words: words_array}],
    caseSensitive: false,
    wordsOnly:true
  });
}
```

And the output is as follows

[image]

The issue is that it highlights any matches of **his** including 't**his**'.

How can I ensure the highlight happens only if a complete match is found? 
The expected output is

This is **his** coat.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to that code's documentation, `words` can contain regular expressions.  Apparently it can *only* contain regular expressions (or at least I see no way in the documentation to disable that.)

Consequently, you will want to search for your words demarcated by word boundaries.  For example, you might use:

```
var words_array = ["\bhis\b"];
```

For additional help with regular expressions, a good reference is here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: I'm not sure if this is still relevant, but there's an open issue about this from 2017: [RegEx dosn't work](https://github.com/garysieling/jquery-highlighttextarea/issues/79). And another from 2015: [Regex highlighting doesn't work?](https://github.com/garysieling/jquery-highlighttextarea/issues/70)

Comment: Here's a [possible alternative plugin](https://github.com/lonekorean/highlight-within-textarea).